# Applying UPPER Operator on an Array of string

Tags: mysql

How can I apply `UPPER` on an array of string in MySQL

E.g. `... WHERE col1 IN UPPER('abc', 'def')`  i.e., I want to match a column value against an array of strings, after applying `UPPER` or any other MySQL string function on each value in the array

Answer (score 0):

UPPER() only takes one argument. You could use it for each value like this:

```
... WHERE col1 IN (UPPER('abc'), UPPER('def'), ...)
```

But it's easier to use a case-insensitive collation, so you don't have to convert the strings to uppercase. MySQL's default collation is already case-insensitive, so you may not have to do anything. If you have defined the `col1` column with a case-sensitive collation, then you would need to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Using UPPER/LOWER functions while comparing the strings is not correct. You must specify needed collation instead.

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  val CHAR(3) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_bin
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'aBC'), (2, 'def'), (3, 'ghI');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aBC |
| 2 | def |
| 3 | ghI |

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE val IN ('abc', 'def');
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | def |

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE val COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci IN ('abc', 'def');
```

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aBC |
| 2 | def |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aghhwyaL)